# MysqlSyntaxError for a correct query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

In my player-entity I am trying to use a formula to include to sum of scores from all players.

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;    
import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

@Entity
public class Player implements IsSerializable {
    @Id 
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false) 
    private Integer score;
    @Formula(value = " SELECT sum(score) ") 
    private Integer totalScore = 0;
    [...]
}
```

However, I am receiving a syntaxerror when loading a player.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
  'SELECT sum(this_.score)  as formula0_0_ from Player this_' at line 1
```

The odd thing is, this query looks totally valid and when I run it on the same database as hibernate does, I am getting the expected result.

```sql
SELECT sum(this_.score) as formula0_0_ from Player this_
1 row(s) returned
```

I have set hibernate to use the mysql dialect

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

Why would jdbc throw an error for a correct query?

Comment: Are you definitely using the correct dialect in your hibernate config as the sql service you're using?

Comment: I believe so, see edit

Comment: Ignorant question, perhaps: should the last `@Formula` value be `"sum(score)"` instead of `"SELECT sum(score)"`?  Perhaps the SQL query being sent to the database is `SELECT SELECT sum(....) from ...`, and MySQL is complaining about the second `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, that change does gets me a little further. I'll do a bit more testing, but you could consider posting that as an answer so I can accept

Comment: Ok, this fixes the problem. I really wish mysql had given me the entire query in the exception.

Comment: @Joost: I've now posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems

```
@Formula(value = " SELECT sum(score) ")
```

should be

```
@Formula(value = " sum(score) ")
```

instead.  It is possible (I haven't tried) that the SQL query being sent to MySQL is

```
SELECT SELECT sum(this_.score) as formula0_0_ from Player this_
```

which is obviously invalid.

MySQL only shows you the SQL string from the point at which it encounters an error.  In your case, this is unhelpful as it happens that from this point onwards you have a valid SQL query.

Comment: Although this answer correctly answers my question (why I was getting a syntax error), it was appearantly not the solution I was looking for. To correctly sum the scores of all players I needed the entire query in parentheses in the formula `@Formula(value="(SELECT sum(p.score) FROM player p)")`